# Fluorescence and excited states?

Tags: visible-light

If a molecule has several excited states, it can get excited by different wavelengths, but it still has only one band gap width. My question is, if I shine a blue light on a molecule and it reaches a high excited state, but the band width gap is that of green light, will the emission of the wavelength to go back to the ground state be blue or green?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will depend on the exact electronic structure of the molecule. In order for a molecule to absorb blue light and emit green light, the excess energy must be lost in some other way, e.g. collisions with other molecules can lead to partial de-excitation, or intermediate emission of low energy photons. This is subject to selection rules for transitions between electronic orbitals.

The band gap only corresponds to the transition from the highest occupied to the lowest unoccupied state. If a blue photon is absorbed, the molecule is in a higher excited state than the lowest possible. If the process taking it from there to the lowest excited state is fast, it will mostly emit green light. If it is not, more likely blue light will be emitted.

This is used for example in the [Nd:YAG Laser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nd:YAG_laser), where electrons are excited to a higher orbital, then quickly relax to a metastable one and from there de-excite (mostly) due to induced emission (if operated as laser at least).

Answer (score 0):

If the wavelength of the blue light emission has not overly elongated due to loss of energy through free space, then the outcome is completely dependent on the molecule.

I believe that if the molecule has a band gap of green light, and lacks one for blue (or any wavelength in between), then there would not be enough energy to excite the electron to a state beyond that of one for green light emission. In this case green light would be emitted.

If there was a bad gap for blue after green, as long as that state is lower than the state of the electron the quanta is coming from, you would see blue.

Does this help?